# Indexers - Which are in use by which projects? Nepomuk, Zeitgeist, Tracker?

Tags: zeitgeist, tracker, nepomuk

I am trying to get an idea if indexers like Zeitgist or Nepomuk are in active use by the various desktops or are they being phased out and replaced?

Most of the documentation online for these seem to be a year or three old, which might indicate that they are not in active development.

What does KDE use now and what are the plans for the next year or so?
Same with Gnome, Unity, LXDE. Where are they going in the next year?

Ubuntu 14.04 will be a LTS support release, so it would be good to know what it's fundamental indexing technology will be.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My research has indicated that all 3 of these are in active use. I went through the manifest files of Ubuntu, UbuntuGnome and Kubuntu and searched through the websites of SuSe and Redhat.

Nepomuk is used in KDE, has been for several years and is in upcoming releases.

Zeigeist is used in Unity and in recent Gnome versions and is in upcoming releases.

Tracker is used in Gnome, has been for several years and is in upcoming releases.

Comment: How is this different than my answer? Also, my answer is more correct, and actually clarifies what Unity uses and what Zeitgeist is not. Zeitgeist is used by some Unity scopes, yes, but it is not an indexer.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, to clarify, Zeitgeist is not an indexer, in the same sense that the systems provided by Nepomuk and Tracker are. Zeitgeist is for logging activity, while Nepomuk/Tracker are for indexing content. The latter are for finding things, and Zeitgeist is for finding when those things were accessed/used.

Nepomuk is the KDE indexing infrastructure. Tracker is the GNOME one. Unity uses Zeitgeist for some stuff, but doesn't actually have a specific indexing service it uses. The Unity dash interacts with scopes, and you could have a scope that searched in Tracker, Nepomuk, Google, or anywhere else.

Comment: So, Kubuntu Desktop installs and runs nepomuk by default, UbuntuGnome Desktop installs and runs tracker by default, and Ubuntu Desktop (Unity) installs and runs scopes and zeitgeist by default? And they are all exclusive? Gnome does not run nepomuk nor zeitgeist, Unity does not run tracker nor nepomuk, KDE does not run zeitgeist nor tracker?